# Using Wireshark to understand layering and Ethernet MAC Frames

Tags: ethernet, wireshark

[Wireshark Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EhH4.png)
I have to fill out some information for a project and I am not sure where to find the information requested. I believe I have the destination and source MAC address correct. But what do I look at for "Ethertype or length? I am using Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

It's the one remaining field in the same Ethernet header that you're already looking at. Wireshark detects this whole section as an Ethernet II header, so it labels the field as just "Type:".

(The frame type is actually *based on* this dual-use field. Values at or below 1500 decimal are interpreted as length and indicate that it's an 802.3 frame. Values higher than that are interpreted as type and indicate that it's an EthII frame.)

Comment: So what are the octets for the ethertype?